# Execute a script to get mouse position in Python & Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium

Hello I am using selenium webdriver to get the position of the cursor in X,Y coordinates in a determined moment on the webdriver screen. I am trying a method that I found by implementing it by using diver.execute_script(), but I am having some issues with the implementation,

I am injecting the script described in the following site: https://www.dev-notes.com/blog/2008/07/30/get-current-mouse-cursor-position-with-javascript/

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


get_cursor_coordinates = """
                    window.onload = init;
                    function init() {
                        if (window.Event) {
                        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
                        }
                        document.onmousemove = getCursorXY;
                    }
                    
                    function getCursorXY(e) {
                        document.getElementById('cursorX').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
                        document.getElementById('cursorY').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
                    }                    
                    """


self.driver.execute_script(get_cursor_coordinates)
script_vars = self.driver.execute_script('getCursorXY(null)')
```

When I execute the script in selenium to get the cursor coordinates, I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: getCursorXY is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)
```

I would like to know how to properly execute the script with Selenium in Python in order to get the X,Y coordinates of the cursor position

Comment: Where are you even declaring your driver? What class is `self` referring to? Context is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You can find mouse position with pyautogui library. Install pyautogui, and then

```
import pyautogui

mousePosition = pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

Comment: Do you know a library where I can find the mouse position in Selenium Remotedriver? I think this gui only woks for selenium local

Comment: that idk how to do. but out of curiosity why are you using RC? from what ive read, selenium webdriver is much better than rc in terms of preventing detection.

Answer (score 0):

Go here: https://github.com/mpodroid/selenium-cursor/blob/main/selenium-cursor.js

Paste the code into a file and save.

Load the js file:

```
driver.execute_script(open("cursor.js").read())
```

Actions like the following should now be reflected visually with a virtual cursor:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h1")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element_with_offset(element, 0, 0).click().perform()
```

Full credit to mpodroid who wrote "selenium-cursor"